# MATCH - AGAINST in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, match-against

I am new in CakePHP and now I can't transform the query:

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH (title, post, tags) AGAINST ('dialux' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as REL
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, post, tags) AGAINST ('dialux' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY REL DESC;
```

in something like this:

```
$this->Post->find('all', xxx);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This is what you need: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: Thank you but i need this form `$this->Post->find('all', xxx);` exactly.

Comment: Exactly the documentation there on how to achieve that for find(all). It is the same as for find(first). Read it again and then try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful as it is from the page that has already been suggested by [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark)

But you could try something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT *, 
MATCH (title, post, tags) AGAINST ('dialux' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as REL
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, post, tags) AGAINST ('dialux' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY REL DESC;';

$this->Post->query($query);
```